# You must specify |clientID| for |GIDSignIn| error when trying to sign in with Google

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-signin

Google sign in was working fine with Xcode 7. After updating to Xcode 8, I started getting the error: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'You must specify |clientID| for |GIDSignIn|'`. I have a GoogleService-Info.plist file with my CLIENT_ID.

I was able to fix it by adding the following line:

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "<CLIENT_ID>"
```

It seems the CLIENT_ID isn't being fetched from GoogleService-Info.plist. I've made sure it's in the Copy Bundle Resources.

[image]

I shouldn't have to specify the client id in the code. How can I fix it to get the information from the GoogleService-Info.plist file?

Answer (score 20):

You can do it this way.

**Swift:**

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
```

**Objective-C**:

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.clientID = FIRApp.defaultApp.options.clientID;
```

Comment: Write this thing in AppDelegate file after FirebaseApp.configure().

Answer (score 8):

Please make sure you have these code place in sequence.

```
FirebaseApp.configure()

GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
```

`FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID` will only able to get data from GoogleService-Info.plist after `FirebaseApp.configure()` is called.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Actually `GoogleServices-Info.plist` had been updated in my case.
I re-downloaded `GoogleServices-Info.plist` and updated it with the older one which fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I solve it with adding forgotten code to AppDelegate class:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <Google/SignIn.h>    

@interface AppDelegate ()<GIDSignInDelegate>

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

#pragma mark - UIApplicationDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    //Google sign-in setup
    NSError* configureError;
    [[GGLContext sharedInstance] configureWithError: &configureError];
    if (configureError) {
        NSLog(@"Error configuring Google services: %@", configureError.localizedDescription);
    }

    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].delegate = self;

    return YES;
}


#pragma mark - GIDSignInDelegate

- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user withError:(NSError *)error {
    //add your code here
}

- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn didDisconnectWithUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user withError:(NSError *)error {
    //add your code here
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

swift 3
in AppDelegate add:

```
var configureError: NSError?
GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \
(String(describing: configureError))")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've arrived here using Google SignIn from Xamarin in iOS then you seem to be required to set the Client Id specifically on the shared SignIn instance in order for the remainder of the process to work. I have a class for managing the callbacks for iOS Google Authentication within which I do the following code:

```
SignIn.SharedInstance.ClientID = "[Client Id Here].apps.googleusercontent.com"; 
SignIn.SharedInstance.Delegate = this;
SignIn.SharedInstance.UIDelegate = this;
SignIn.SharedInstance.SignInUser();
```

I'd recommend obviously putting this client id in a configuration setting somewhere although I had assumed it would just pick up the client id from the GoogleServices-Info.plist present, but it didn't.

I also have the GoogleServices-Info.plist in my 'Resources' folder which is set to BundledResource for build and this I downloaded from the Google Developer Console for my app and then renamed it to 'GoogleServices-Info.plist' from its rather long given name. Finally, also worth looking out for, I set the 'Entitlements.plist' setting specifically in the iOS Bundle Signing page under Custom Entitlements which gets you past the Key Chain error you will inevitably see. Don't forget to 'Enable Keychain' in the Entitlements themselves too.

Answer (score 0):

Despite doing everything my app was crashing on tapping `GIDSignInButton`
.In my case I moved the code of setting  clientID from Appdelegate to where the **GIDSignInButton** was kept (LoginViewController say).

```
public override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureViews()
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "Your_ClientID"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're here because you're using [this Unity asset](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/google-login-ios-android-94517) and it crashes on iOS but not on Android: make sure to call `LCGoogleLoginBridge.InitWithClientID()` before trying to log in.