# How to solve You must specify |clientID| for |GIDSignIn| error in ios

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

i am working in Gmail login features in unity. When the user clicks the sign in with google button the email id  stored in google play services will automatically populate in screen . Then user choose desired id and login it. In Android it is working. But when i
shift to ios  i am receiving the error

```
static void UncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *exception)

{

NSLog(@"Uncaught exception: %@: %@\n%@", [exception name], [exception reason], [exception callStackSymbols]);

if (gsCrashReporterUEHandler)

    gsCrashReporterUEHandler(exception);

}


Thread 1: "You must specify |clientID| for |GIDSignIn|"

This is my pod file . I have changed google sign in less than 4 version.
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 4.0'
pod 'GoogleUtilities'
```

I have changed the client id  for ios also. and i have downloaded the latest googleserviceinfo.list from firebase console also.  But it shows the error. So any one can help me . How to solve this error.

I have searched this  below forum. But it did nt solved my error.

[You must specify |clientID| for |GIDSignIn| error when trying to sign in with Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39731783/you-must-specify-clientid-for-gidsignin-error-when-trying-to-sign-in-with-go)

I have searched similar questions in stackoverflow. But no one gives the correct solutions.So dont mark my questions as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution. In  Stackoverflow there are similar questions but the answers are Lengthy.

This is  the simplest solution.

After select the Google-Service-Info.plist file from the "Project navigator" window, you will see on the right the "Target Membership" section. Add the check mark to you application and try rebuild the app.
It works for me!

[image]